# Using wordpress user accounts with an iOS app

Tags: iphone, ios, wordpress, authentication, content-management-system

Hey so I'm building an iOS app. The fist window is a login screen where people login using their login information from the wordpress blog. 
I've considered xml-rpc but it doesn't allow a registration from the phone.
Then I looked at using a RESTful api but I have no idea how to connect it to the wordpress db to check if the username and password are correct. 
There are quite a few puling for wordpress that set up RESTful APIs but none of them appear to help with what I'm trying to do.

Any help would be very much appreciated!

Comment: Why don't you just call a webview that links to your blog registration form ? then, for the authentification and the rest of the funcationnalities, just use the xml-rpc method.

Comment: I would rather not... =/ but if that's the only choice, I guess I'll have to go with that

Comment: I didn't search for the API functionality you're looking for but, if I were you, I would use a webview or create a "php" file that will insert a user in my database.

Comment: and I can't find the set of xml-rpc class files that work with arc

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Figured out how to do it. You can do it with xml-rpc. Here's the code I have in my request plugin if anyone ever needs it:

```
function register_user($args){

    require_once( ABSPATH . WPINC . '/registration.php' );

/* Check if users can register. */
$registration = get_option( 'users_can_register' );

    /* If user registered, input info. */


        $userdata = array(
            'user_pass' => esc_attr( $args[2] ),
            'user_login' => esc_attr( $args[0] ),
            'first_name' => esc_attr( "" ),
            'last_name' => esc_attr( "" ),
            'nickname' => esc_attr( "" ),
            'user_email' => esc_attr( $args[1] ),
            'user_url' => esc_attr( "" ),
            'aim' => esc_attr( "" ),
            'yim' => esc_attr( ""),
            'jabber' => esc_attr( "" ),
            'description' => esc_attr( "" ),
            'role' => get_option( 'default_role' ),
        );

        if ( !$userdata['user_login'] ){
            $error = __('A username is required for registration.', 'frontendprofile');
            return "user-invalid";      
        }elseif ( username_exists($userdata['user_login']) ){
            $error = __('Sorry, that username already exists!', 'frontendprofile');
            return "user-used";
        }elseif ( !is_email($userdata['user_email'], true) ){
            $error = __('You must enter a valid email address.', 'frontendprofile');
            return "email-invalid"; 
        }elseif ( email_exists($userdata['user_email']) ){
            $error = __('Sorry, that email address is already used!', 'frontendprofile');
            return "email-used";
        }
        else{
            $new_user = wp_insert_user( $userdata );
            wp_new_user_notification($new_user, $user_pass); //send the user an email with the information

            return "success";
        }

     update_user_meta( $args[0]->ID, 'setup', "0" );


}
```

Comment: Thanks for the code, but how to use it, care to elaborate? Many thanks!